# Python - Earliest date of JPG file creation

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library, exif

I want to create a function that is going to search for metadata of JPG files using [exifread](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead), select the earliest date from `Image DateTime` tag and print it. Here is the code I have so far (not much :D):

```
def GetExifTagsForFile(filename):
  file = open(filename,'rb')
  tags = exifread.process_file(file)
```

Usually, I would further create a list where I add all dates and then using `min` select the earliest date. However, here I am trying to operate with `IfdTag` for which this kind of solution will not work. The encoding of `IfdTag` is  `%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S`. I have also tried to change tag's format to `datetime` using `strdtime`, however, this solution works only for strings.  Do you have any suggestions how to solve my problem?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of `IfdTag`, it's hard to say.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The format is '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S'.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @SiHa this depends on how your tag is encoded. I think it should be `"YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS"`. In this case bring your tags first to string and then to datetime format, where you can use `min()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_objects = [datetime.strptime(str(t['IfdTag'].values), '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S') for t in tag_list]
min(datetime_objects)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, it seems that `strptime` does not work with `IfdTag`.

Comment: I included a conversion to string-format. This has worked for me at least.